# Looking for a facebook friends selector dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog

I am developing facebook app with Python and google app engine and I am searching for facebook friends selector dialog (having identical layout as the one facebook provides for inviting friends to your app). What I need is a dialog allowing user to select friends by clicking their photos (icons) and sending back to the app the list of selected friends (without any notification being sent to the selected friends).

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [this jQuery plugin](http://archives-mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html) in some of my apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this  [Facebook Friend Selector v1.2.1](http://facebook-friend-selector.codersgrave.com/)